# HTML5 Canvas compositing  (source-in)

Tags: html, canvas, composite

I am trying to recreate a page flipping type animation in HTML5 using canvas. The animation is based on ideas from [this page](http://oreilly.com/javascript/archive/flashhacks.html). But that's not really important. The problem I am having is that using the 'source-in' composite operation is not giving me the results I expect and would like clarification as to why. I think it only works on chrome, not working on FF 3.6.

The black rectangle is supposed to act as a 'mask' for the page being turned over. All I want to see is the turning page in the areas where it overlaps the mask. The problem is the entire black rectangle is drawn, not just the area where they overlap.

I know HTML5 isn't really being used yet, I'm just experimenting for my personal site and curiosity. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTML5, while still experimental, is already being used and the browser support isn't that bad either.

Comment: The sample code is a broken link. Wondering if this should be closed as it appears too specific, and the example to view doesn't even exist anymore. Wondering if there needs to be an "abandoned project" answer.

Answer (score 5):

Canvas Compositing support was broken and might still be incomplete in some browsers.

Compare the [images here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing)
with [the actual rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html) in your browser to see what works in which browser right now.

Comment: It's about a year since you posted this comment. Looks like Firefox 4 is all good. Chrome 11 is failing source-in (looks like source-atop), source-out (looks like xor), destination-in (doesn't copy anything), destination-atop (looks like destination-over) and copy (looks like source-over). That's a bit disappointing, but at least it should be safe to use the other ones. Can anybody test this in IE9?

Comment: Six months later. Chrome 15 is good on all of them. Firefox 8 no longer supports darker. IE9 won't load the page at all (some sort of error about the onload event), so I can't tell what it supports.